# ngx-serial and PLC sending and getting Inputs/outputs

Tags: angular, typescript, serial-port, plc, ngxs

I have a problem with sending signals through web application to the outputs. I am using Angular web application and ngx-serial library with FATEK PLC and I made a connection by using connect method from ngx-serial library but when I try to send signals to the output I am making some mistake, because i see that RX led lightens but output led did not. For example, I need to light led on output Y2, and i tried with using sendData method like this :   this.serial.sendData("Y2\n"); //Y2\n
because ngx-serial worked for me when I used arduino and also it established connection between my app and PLC, but maybe I am using wrong keyword(string) for sendData method... Do you have any idea or set of keywords, or maybe some kind of library for getting or setting Input/Output referrences from Angular web application for FATEK PLC?

```
this.serial.sendData("2\n");
this.serial.sendData("Y2\n");
this.serial.sendData("Y2"); 
this.serial.sendData("2");
this.serial.sendData("Y2:1\n"); //L1\n
this.serial.sendData("Y2:1"); //L1\n
```